# Tensorflow: can one prevent one branch of tf.where from executing?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm working on an encoder-decoder setup. I want to be able to run the encoder once and then perform multiple decoder runs. The solution I've come up with is to feed the decoder with a TF conditional node (using tf.where) which contains either the final hidden state of the encoder (in which case TF will run the encoder when I ask for the decoder output), or a placeholder with the stored results of the encoder (in which case in theory TF does not need to run the encoder).

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
encoder_state = tf.where(gen_math_ops.greater_equal(branching_points, 0), encoder_state,
                         rnn.static_rnn(encoder_cell, encoder_inputs, dtype=dtype)[1])
```

As I don't get a speedup from this method, I'm pretty sure it doesn't work and both branches of the tf.where are run by TF everytime, even when it only needs to read from the placeholder.

Is there any way to use tf.where such that it does not run the encoder? I've looked at the description of the method and I'm not sure whether both branches are always computed or not, I've seen contradictory information on this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [`tf.cond()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) function can be used when you want to defer execution of one of the branches until the predicate has been evaluated.

```
encoder_state = tf.cond(
    tf.greater_equal(branching_points, 0),
    lambda: encoder_state,
    lambda: tf.nn.static_rnn(encoder_cell, encoder_inputs, dtype=dtype)[1])
```

Comment: tf.cond only works on scalars. So this will not work if branching_points is a Tensor of bool values which in this case it seems like it is

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating a model with tf.cond and feeding a dictionary but tf.cond  will only take one input so this will not work if you have multiple branching_points.
I have created workaround but Its pretty convoluted and I would love to see a better solution for this especially that this **only increases performance** if the true_fn and false_fn are computationally expensive. 
This solution can also be useful if true_fn or false_fn should not be executed if their branch is not picked (for example if youre using tf.assign in those functions)

First i create the bool tensors:

```
branch_1 = tf.greater_equal(branching_points, 0)
branch_2 = tf.logical_not(branch_1)
```

Then I use a boolean mask to only execute the True conditions from the branches

```
result_1 = tf.boolean_mask(branch_1)
result_2 = tf.boolean_mask(branch_2)
```

finally you can form one tensor if you need to. 
If order matters you can use the `tf.where(tf.equal(branch_1,True))` and `tf.where(tf.equal(branch_2,True))` to get the indexes of the result_1 and result_2 respectively. Then you apply [tf.scatter_nd](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd).
If order doesnt matter you can simply use [tf.concat](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat)